# Auto Facebook Login with Curl

Tags: facebook, curl, authentication

I'm trying to autologin to facebook using curl, but nothing will work. The nearest I got was that I logged in in my current window (so I had the normal facebook-homepage on my-server.com/facebooklogin.php), but when I open facebook.com in a new tab I'm not logged in anymore.

Does someone know how I can login into facebook with cURL/PHP or maybe something else?

Code: [Select]

```
function Send_to_Server($url) {
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'email='.urlencode('MyEmail@Email.com').'&pass='.urlencode('MyPassword').'&login=Login');
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,0);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
    $result = curl_exec ($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
    return $result;
}   

$string = Send_to_Server('https://login.facebook.com/login.php?m&next=http%3A%2F%2Fm.facebook.com%2Fhome.php');

echo $string;
```

That doesn't work :D I don't have any output and I'm not logged in in facebook

Greetings

Comment: This sounds browser specific, and like you're somehow not getting/keeping the session cookies...

Answer (score 0):

Not really possible and even if you could find a way to do it it's probably against their TOS.  What are you trying to do?  Maybe you could create an app and grant yourself offline_access to generate a long lasting token and use that to meet your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

this seems to have what you want...
www.360percents.com/posts/php-curl-status-update-working-example